# RVS in SCIPY Python

Tags: python, scipy

In scipy.stats most of distribution have rvs method, which provides random samples.
But I didn't find explanation random samples of what?
probability? No, because it more than 1.

Comment: you may want to understand the concept of a random variable, before you deal with distributions of random variables. See e.g here: http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/ranvar.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, invoking an **rvs** method once produces a single value of a pseudorandom variable, *not* a pseudorandom sample. For instance, here we see the results of a series of invocations of the rvs method for the beta distribution with shape parameters 1 and 3.

```
>>> from scipy.stats import beta
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.11573182734943342
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.711001211281741
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.13358246108665714
```

If it's necessary to repeat a series of pseudorandom values for this distribution then the **random_state** parameter can be used, as indicated here.

```
>>> beta.rvs(1,3,random_state=1)
0.2570633444085756
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.006105422238509487
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.03773135132269083
>>> beta.rvs(1,3,random_state=1)
0.2570633444085756
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.006105422238509487
>>> beta.rvs(1,3)
0.03773135132269083
```

**Clarification** (I hope):

The full signature for `beta.rvs` is:

`rvs(a, b, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)`

When I first wrote that this method produces a single value of a pseudorandom variable, I should have indicated that this would be *by default*, since `size=1`. That is, the method produces a sample of size one by default. The method is obviously capable of producing larger (pseudo-)random samples by setting its `size` parameter to values greater than one.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between a single value of a pseudorandom variable and a random sample?

Comment: @StefanFabian: Thanks for your comment. I've edited my answer in hopes of clarifying.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the quick reply! I think I got the misunderstanding but just to be sure. What confused me was your first sentence "[...] produces a single value of a pseudorandom variable, not a random sample". With "not a random sample", you mean sample as in a sample containing multiple values sampled from the distribution. Because, if I'm not mistaken, a single value of a (pseudo-)random variable is basically a single (pseudo-)random sample from a distribution, isn't it?

Comment: That's right! I wasn't careful enough in my use of language. I was concentrating too much on the question, I suppose.